# Duplicate values issue in Android Studio gradle

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-gradle-3.1.0

I have been trying to add a dependency of **com.shamanland:fonticon:0.1.8** but as I add this I get the error

> **error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/textSize' with config ''. 
>   error: resource previously defined here.**

There are too many values with duplication issue to remove the values.
I have tried changing compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to 25 but this did not help either.
I tried to use exclude but I don't know what to exclude exactly. Can anyone help me with this issue? Thank you.

My gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
configurations {
    all*.exclude module: 'okhttp'
    all*.exclude module: 'okio'
}
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '27.0.2'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.abc.def"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 15
    versionName "1.2.4"
    multiDexEnabled = true

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        lintOptions {
            disable 'MissingTranslation'
            checkReleaseBuilds false
        }
        minifyEnabled false
    }
}
aaptOptions {
    cruncherEnabled = false
}
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
}
}
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots" }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'
    provided 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.16'
    compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.8'
    annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.16"
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.6.0'
    compile 'com.chauthai.swipereveallayout:swipe-reveal-layout:1.4.0'
    compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.4.+'
    compile 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.0.2'
    compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.2.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.github.jd-alexander:library:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.1'
    compile 'com.yarolegovich:discrete-scrollview:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.miguelcatalan:materialsearchview:1.4.0'
    compile 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.ksoichiro:android-observablescrollview:1.5.0'
    compile 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.hedgehog.ratingbar:app:1.1.2'
    compile 'com.eftimoff:android-pathview:1.0.8@aar'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    compile 'com.stone.vega.library:VegaLayoutManager:1.0.1'
    compile project(':library')
    compile 'me.henrytao:smooth-app-bar-layout:24.1.0.0'
    compile project(':PayTabs_SDK')

    /*----------------payfort sdk------------*/

    implementation 'com.victor:lib:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.shamanland:fonticon:0.1.8'
    implementation('com.nispok:snackbar:2.11.+') {
        // exclusion is not necessary, but generally a good idea.
        exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'support-v7'
    }
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
    implementation 'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk16:1.46'
    implementation 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10'

    implementation project(':FORTSDKv1.4.4')

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be due to the implementation of other external dependency. In my case, I try removing the external dependency one by one. Most Probably while adding dependency the same dependency was used on other external dependency. So try removing library dependency one by one and see which was causing problem.

Comment: yes thank you i tried removing dependencies one by one and found out that it was caused by another library i was using which had same values i just removed and updated values of the other library which solved the problem.